# most efficient way to read data from stdin in python

Tags: python, stdin

I know the most efficient way to read data from file in chunks. But I want to read data from stdin and I want the fastest way to read data because time is a constraint in the execution of the code. I want to do this in python 2.7.

Edit:
Judging the best method to read data from stdin will depend on a lot of parameters. What things should I take into consideration in order to read data faster?

Code:

```
from itertools import permutations
line=raw_input().splitlines()[0].split(" ")
word=line[0]
k=int(line[1])
words=list(permutations(word,k))
finalList=[]
for word in words:
    wo=""
    for w in word:
        wo=wo+w
    finalList.append(wo)
finalList.sort()
for i in finalList:
    print i
```

Comment: We are not a code-writing service. This is not a question -- it's a list of specifications for a program you want written.

Comment: If time is of the essence, do not use Python perhaps.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I know the different methods like raw_input, sys.stdin. I just wanted to know which one is the fastest.

Comment: Then why not benchmark them yourself?  Also consider the effect of different buffer sizes.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The computations I have to do for the code can be done faster in python. That is the reason I chose python.

Comment: Sorry I should clarify. We are not a code benchmarking service either.

Comment: @sohil. They can be written faster maybe, but not executed faster than say a good C implementation.

Comment: @cdarke I am relatively new to coding in python. I have been coding for just 2 months. Could you please tell me what all factors should i consider apart from the buffer sizes.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you. I will consider writing them in C as well.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I do not want the exact solution. Some guidance as to how I should proceed and what things I should take into consideration would also help.

Comment: I think you should not worry about speed if you have an even remotely modern computer. If it becomes a problem, you will have something specific to solve.

Comment: @sohil: how is data t be placed into `stdin`?  That is, where is the data coming from?

Comment: The purpose of Python is to be easy to write. You should make your code as easy to write/read as possible: forget about the optimization for now.

Comment: @cdarke the data is going to come from the terminal, as in I will be entering the data from the terminal. I know reading from files can be done, but for now I want to work on entering data from the terminal

Comment: @MadPhysicist I know that is the purpose of Python. I have written a code to perform some logic. Now I want to evaluate what are the areas where I can optimize the algorithm.

Comment: Then post your code.

Comment: @MadPhysicist please check the edit

Comment: If the data is being entered by a user typing at the keyboard then any discussion on I/O efficiency is pointless.

Comment: @cdarke It was just a question out of curiosity to know the fastest method.

Comment: You should consider learning about the `timeit` module. It will tell you which way is fastest.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `fileinput` module. A good way to read from `STDIN` using this is as such

```
import fileinput as fi

for line in fi.input():
  // DO SOMETHING
```